# emacs character before point equals

Tags: emacs, comments, char, point

How to check whether the character before point equals "`\`"

```
(defun comment-latex () 
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p) 
      (comment-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (if (= (char-before) ("\\")                 ;; how to fix this sentence?     
       (insert "%")
      (if (= (point) (line-beginning-position)) ;; this part works
        (insert "% ")
       (end-of-line)
       (insert " % "))))
)
(global-set-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "%") 'comment-latex)
```

The code as example should be doing the following:

1) If a region is selected, the region should be commented.

2) If the character before point is a "`\`", a normal % should be inserted at point.

3) If point is at the beginning of line, insert a "`%`"

4) If point is anywhere else, go to the end of the sentence and insert "`SPC` `%` `SPC`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for individual characters is ?*char*. So:

```
(= (char-before) ?\\)
```

Comment: The reason I gave you the answer is because apparently you helped the other one with his answer. Technically, his answer is more complete though. I'm not sure who to hand the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with

```
(= (char-before) 92)
```

92 is the ASCII code of the \ character.

Answer (score 1):

In e-lisp, a character is not the same as a string. The syntax for getting the ascii value of a character is `?a`. Try something like:

```
(if (= (char-before) ?\\))
    DO-SOMETHING
  DO-SOMETHING-ELSE)
```

Comment: The character to look for was \, and equal is pointless since we are comparing integers.

Comment: Fixed the " vs. \ problem (read the original code too fast). Also, dropped the recommendation to use `equal` as I can't find a good reference to where the `eq`, `equal`, and `=` functions are being discussed. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Basically: Eq and = compares if the values are the same. IE, 10 is 10. equal compares if they have the same value. (equal (foo . bar) (foo . bar)) is true, but (= (foo . bar) (foo . bar) ) is not since they are two different cons-cells.